# VBA String off all values in a range without duplicates

Tags: arrays, vba, string, split, range

Hello I have a range defined by the code:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim range as range
Range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, LastColumn))
```

The cells in that range contain a long string of which I only need a specific part taht I extract with a split function

```
Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value, " , ")(1)
```

What I need to do is to get all the unique values from defined range without duplicates as a string where different values are divided by " and ". There usually will be only one or two different values occurring so if there's just one of a kind, the string would just say "Occurance1" and if more then "occurance1" & " and " "Occurance2".

I have tried some complex and long ways to extract all the values by going through columns one by one and comparing the occurance1 and occurance2 which I feel and am sure is a bad way to do it, as I'm sure there's like a 1-2 line code to just get all the unique values in specified range.

Could someone, please, help me with the code for this?

My complex code is something like this

```
Dim ProductSupport1 As String
ProductSupport1 = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value, " , ")(1)

Dim ProductSupport2 As String

For i = 1 To NumberOfFormats
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "" Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Parameters", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, 3).Select
End If

ProductSupport2 = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value, " , ")(1)


If ProductSupport2 = ProductSupport1 And i = NumberOfFormats Then
GoTo ProductSupportFinish
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select
Next i
ProductSupportFinish:
InitialFormat.Select

Debug.Print ProductSupport1 & ", " & ProductSupport2
```

Which is long, messy, complex and not universal, and it doesn't handle the situation in which both occurances are the same at the end which I can easily fix, but it still gives me OCD

Comment: I am afraid that nobody will like the way you show us the code, to try understanding it. You firstly should use Sheets variables in order to present what you **really** need in a more compact way. Something like `Dim wsM as Worksheet` followed by `Set wsM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification")`. Then change the long sausages in something easy to be read and understood. You  should be sure that the `Find` function really returns a cell, so use `Dim cellF as range`, followed by `Set cellF = wsM.Cells(Cells.Find("Product Support", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column)`.

Comment: Everything in my code works, the problem is that the logical chain of actions is definitely too long, and I am looking if there's a function that returns an array of unique values that are in the specific range

Comment: Then use `If not cellF Is Nothing Then` and only after that you should use the rest of the code involving `Split`, comparing etc. I am maybe to tired, but I cannot keep the understanding step with your code. Maybe somebody else more patient will do it...

Comment: I was not referring to the code logic, since I did not have enough patience to read it as it looks. But, you will maybe be lucky with somebody else.

Comment: You see I set occurance 1 and 2 and then I go through all the columns in range till I weather find or not find a value that's different from the first one, assuming that there can only be max 2 different values in the range